# Is it possible to suppress an Abaqus "Tie Constraint" on a different step of a simulation?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to incorporate gravity in a simulation involving cohesive surfaces.  The geometry changes when I turn gravity on and I'm curious if I can "Tie" the surfaces together and allow gravity to be applied to the model.  Once everything settles (i.e. kinetic energy is at a minimum) I can suppress the tie interface and look at cohesive surfaces between the two bodies of interest?

I'm wondering if I can have a Gravity step with a tied constraint followed by a step that suppresses that tie constraint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, you can change the contact definition during the simulation. So, for example, you can use hard contact with no separation at the beginning of the analysis and after changing it to the one you need.

Comment: I still had separation using Rough tangential friction and no separation with hard contact.  An alternative that kept the two surfaces in contact to simulate a "Tie constraint" was to use the default cohesive surface contact behavior.  Approximately the same computational time.  Thank you!!!